How to run Application.Ontime directly in LibreOffice Basic?
I have written a code that executes every second. I have a global array that I modify, but with each run of the Logic function, this global variable is empty, from which I conclude that it is being executed in a new context. What should I do to be able to call the Logic function directly?
Option VbaSupport 1
Option Explicit

global Dim ArrPump as TPump

Sub Logic(ByVal oEvent)
    ' i do this some logic with ArrPump
    Call NextRun 
End Sub


Sub NextRun()
    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")     'прибавляем к текущему времени 3 сек
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Standard.Module1.Logic"     'назначаем следующий запуск
End Sub
 

I would like something like this, so that the function is called in the same context, and the global array will not be new every time.
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, Logic

You mentioned earlier that you had a solution where the data is stored in a spreadsheet instead of requiring a global variable to persist between calls. Is that no longer working?
